# Search in pandas Dataframe column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data as pandas Dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'id': [1,2,3,4, 5],
        'first_name': ['Sheldon', 'Raj', 'Leonard', 'Howard', 'Amy'],
        'last_name': ['Copper', 'Koothrappali', 'Hofstadter', 'Wolowitz', 'Fowler'],
        'movie_ids': ['34,265,268,65', 
                      '34,43,65,61', 
                      '5,876,8',
                      '14,5,268',
                      '134,845,2']}).set_index(["id"], drop=False)
```

and a list of ids:

```
movie_ids = ['34','845']
```

I would like to get the indexes of those rows where any of the movie_ids' item is represented in the movie_ids column.
I was trying to convert the column value to list than filter on that, with that I get only the matched values:

```
result = list(filter(lambda x: set(countries).intersection(set(x.split(","))), df['movie_ids'].values))
```

than using loc fn to get only those rows:

```
df = df.loc[df['movie_ids'].isin(result)]
```

But I guess this is not the most efficient way, for example with the millions of rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
df[df.movie_ids.str.contains(rf"\b{'|'.join(movie_ids)}\b")]

    id first_name     last_name      movie_ids
id                                            
1    1    Sheldon        Copper  34,265,268,65
2    2        Raj  Koothrappali    34,43,65,61
5    5        Amy        Fowler      134,845,2
```